# opencv namedWindow() doesnot create a window with the correct name

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I am using `namedWindow(windowName,size)` to create a namedWindow using OpenCV. However, the created window's name does not match the name specified in the function call.
This leads to imshow()  creating a new window every time it is called.

EDIT:

```
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0  
    if (!cap.isOpened()) // if not success, exit program  
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video  
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video  
    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    Ref<Reader> reader(new MultiFormatReader);

    std::string windowname = "ABC";
    namedWindow(windowname, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"
```

If I include the `iostream` header file, the name of created window contains the sub-string 'ABC' along with some other junk characters. If I don't include the aforementioned header file, the window name only contains junk characters

Comment: Can't really help without looking at the code. Can you post the problematic code along with your question please? Make sure you include the lines where you're calling imshow() and namedWindow().

Comment: I added the necessary source code.

Comment: probably you linked debug libraries to release build, or vice-versa!

Comment: thanks Micka that worked. I was using the release libraries in debug mode.